# Networking stop/waiting error

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualization, dhcp, kvm-virtualization

I wanted to set up a bridge connection for my VMs (I am using KVM).
I modified my `etc/network/interfaces` file and its contents are:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_fd 9
bridge_hello 2
bridge_maxage 12
bridge_stp off
```

After modifying the `etc/network/interfaces` file I wanted to make them active so I run the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

but I got the following output:

```
Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces
```

so I tried restarting network by the following command:

```
sudo service networking stop && sudo service networking start
```

I get the following output:

```
stop: unknown instance:
```

If I do :

```
sudo service networking start
```

I get :

```
networking stop/waiting
```

and my net has stopped working after that. I am using `Ubuntu 12.04` and have a wired DHCP connection.

Please try to resolve this issue so that I can successfully configure bridge for my VMs and get back my net connection.

Comment: I've found two posts that would help you. If you have not tried these then you can give them a try: [How to setup bridged networking in KVM - Tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/kvm-bridged.html) and [KVM/Networking](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking)

Answer (score 3):

As you found you are getting a warning doing it the way you mentioned. If your physically at your computer do this:

```
sudo ifdown -a
sudo ifup -a
```

For SSH session one should read:

http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/debian-running-etcinit-dnetworking-restart-is-deprecated-because-it-may-not-enable-again-some-interfaces/

Anyhow for SSH you might do this:

```
sudo nohup sh -c "ifdown eth0 -a && ifup eth0 -a"
```

another suggestion about bridging is mentioned here:
http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/debian-running-etcinit-dnetworking-restart-is-deprecated-because-it-may-not-enable-again-some-interfaces/#comment-2108

Answer (score 0):

I did sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart and my net started working.

Also, the command:

brctl show

shows my bridge is created.

My problem is solved!